# Podio API last_edit_on filter weird behavior

Tags: ruby, podio

I'm trying to retrieve all the items edited since a specific datetime with this filter:

```
last_sync = DateTime.new(...)
filters = {last_edit_on: {from: last_sync}} 
Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(app_id, filters).all
```

This filter not working, I tested different values to see if it was a time offset issue.

```
filters = {last_edit_on: {from: 1.hour.from_now}} 
Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(app_id, filters).all.count # > 0
```

Non zero count, despite having items edited in the future does not make sense. I even tried with relative values, and I still get items with a last_edit_on in the future.

```
filters = {last_edit_on: {from: '+0d', to: '+1d'}} 
Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(app_id, filters).all.count # > 0
```

If I filter with further times like `{from: '+1d', to: '+2d'}` or 
`{from: 2.days.from_now}` I finally have a zero count, which makes me think I'm using correctly this filter.

Am I missing something or is there an issue in the last_edit_on filter system ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works to get items edited in last 4 days (as example)

```
filter = {:last_edit_on => {:from => '-4d', :to => '+0d'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, that's the way I was using it. But the from and to seem broken as I get items modified 2 days ago when I use {from: '-1d', to: '+0d'}. Or even items when I ask for last_edit_on from the future.

Comment: That might be different ways of thinking about `+0d` and `-0d` :)